# Проблема с записью в значений в dat файл

Tags: c++, gnuplot

Мне нужно построить график функции распределения. Для этого я решил использовать GnuPlot.
В Excel пробовал, хорошо, но ступеньки плохо выраженные из-за малого количества значений.

Делаю по [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-YPZDe_BYw&list=LLvHoSeAd7FzRzWSEu-b11OA&index=5&t=0s), и при записи в `*.dat` файл записывает только первую строку, а не все значения.

Как исправить?

Вектор `arr`содержит концы интервалов, HLP вычисленные вероятности.
Делаю данное из-за малого количества точек для построения.

```
cout << "____________________________" << endl;
    float x = float(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i<arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((arr[i]>x) && (x >= arr[i - 1]))
        {
            ofstream outval;
            outval.open("tst.dat", ios::app);
            outval << x << " " << HLP[i-1] << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
            cout << x <<"  "<< HLP[i - 1] << endl;
        }
        x += 0.1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ой. Смотрите, вы прошлись по циклу, нашли, где находится `x`, в каком интервале, и идете себе дальше, увеличив `x` на 0.1. Вы уверены, что он при этом попадет в один из *следующих* интервалов?

Вам нужно цикл по `x`, и для каждого значения `x` искать интервал, куда он попадает.

Comment: про открытие файла в цикле спасибо, можна было оставить, а  для`х` я добавил внешнее условие `while(x!=arr[arr.size() - 1])`

Comment: дошло как результат вывел)

Answer (score 0):

Собственно спасибо Harry

1) необходимо было вынести открытие файла за цикл, так как файл перезаписывался.

Короче сделал так:

```
cout << "____________________________" << endl;
    float x = float(arr[0]);
    ofstream outval;
    outval.open("tst.dat", ios::app);
    while (x != arr[arr.size() - 1])
    {

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((arr[i] > x) && (x >= arr[i - 1]))
            {

                outval << x << " " << HLP[i - 1] << endl;
                cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
                cout << x << "  " << HLP[i - 1] << endl;
            }

        }
        x += 0.1;
    }
```